# How to implement: click a button, then user can input something to a EditText

Tags: android, ime

There is an EditText(`edit`) and a Button(`btn`) on screen.

User can click the EditText to input something, and I also want when user click the button, user can input something to the EditText too.

I tried:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnclickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
       edit.requestFocus();
       edit.performClick();
   }
});
```

But it doesn't work. Although `edit` get the focus, but the IME doesn't show.

Comment: @AalokSharma, that's not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`performClick()` works only when you implement the `onClickListener` for that particular View.

So, do this in the `onClick` of your `EditText` or `Button`

```
edit.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(edit, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```